# How to sync sqlite with a REST web-service in IOS

Tags: sqlite, rest, ios8, xcode6

Is there a good tutorial on how to sync a sqlite to a REST web-service. I have been searching this in the internet and found none. I'm working on a simple app that collects user information and 'POST' it in the web-service and 'Get' to store on local sqlite db on iphone. If there's no internet connection it will automatically store on the local db and will update the web-service if there is an internet connection. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also search for a tutorial but haven´t found a tutorial and the tutorial I found was outdated: https://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1 
So I kept searching and found:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/206310/data-synchronization-in-mobile-apps-multiple-devices-multiple-users

Where they mention the optimistic and pessimistic offline locks that you can help you for what you want. 
Also you check this answer: [Syncing Database (sqlite) from WebService(Json/XML) for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916662/syncing-database-sqlite-from-webservicejson-xml-for-ios)